# merge a array of object with parent and child relation with another array of object having child values

Tags: javascript, jquery, es6-modules

merge a array of object with parent and child relation with an other array of object having only child values to fetch resultant array of object combining common values in both

I have a Array of object with parent child value

```
    submenu : [{
    text: 'Website',
    permissionId : 900,
    submenu:[{
            text: 'Publisher Site',
            permissionId : 901
        },

        {
            text: 'Track Disable',
            permissionId : 902
        },

        {
            text: 'Goals',
            permissionId : 904
        }]
}]
```

and another array of object with child value

```
       submenu:[ {
            text: 'Publisher Site',
            permissionId : 901
        },
        {
            text: 'Track Disable',
            permissionId : 902
        }
        ]
```

and we need resultant array of object like this

```
   submenu : [{ 
    text: 'Website',
    permissionId : 900,
    submenu:  [{
            text: 'Publisher Site',
            permissionId : 901
        },
        {
            text: 'Track Disable',
            permissionId : 902
        }
        ]
     } ]
```

Comment: why {text: 'Website',
    permissionId : 900,} is included in final object ?
it is not common right ?

Comment: no the final array we need {text: 'Website', permissionId : 900,} by combining both objects that the expected result

Answer (score 0):

I have consumed both objects in a and b variables.

```
a = { submenu : [{
    text: 'Website',
    permissionId : 900,
    submenu:[{
            text: 'Publisher Site',
            permissionId : 901
        },

        {
            text: 'Track Disable',
            permissionId : 902
        },

        {
            text: 'Goals',
            permissionId : 904
        }]
}] }

b = {
submenu:[ {
            text: 'Publisher Site',
            permissionId : 901
        },
        {
            text: 'Track Disable',
            permissionId : 902
        }
        ]
}
var c = b.submenu;
   a.submenu[0].submenu = a.submenu[0].submenu.filter((elm)=> c.find(e=>e.permissionId == elm.permissionId));
console.log(a);
```

Output -

```
submenu: Array(1)
0:
permissionId: 900
submenu: Array(2)
0: {text: "Publisher Site", permissionId: 901}
1: {text: "Track Disable", permissionId: 902}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
text: "Website"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
```